# PHPGRID_ERROR: Could not execute query. Error 101

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpgrid

I'm trying to integrate phpgrid lite with CodeIgniter, I've done all functions correctly as per the procedure in phpgrid website but It's showing error: 
`PHPGRID_ERROR: Could not execute query. Error 101`

Answer (score 3):

From the error message, it indicates a Sql query failed to execute. So it may not be related to CI at all. Assuming you have followed either [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1008252/phpGrid-and-Codeigniter-Integration) or [this](http://phpgrid.com/example/phpgrid-and-codeigniter-integration/) tutorial, however, you did not post any code snippet so it's hard to determine the root cause of the error.

You should first enable DEBUG (https://phpgrid.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/215888) and find out the Sql that is throwing error.

Answer (score 1):

Set DEBUG to true in conf.php

```
define('DEBUG', true);
```

Open developer tool in web browser for any Sql error messages.

[image]